# Overcoming the BX-only-indexing restriction

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm implementing a simple 0-terminated string printing function using BIOS interrupt `int 10h`.

The procedure is as follows:

- Pop from stack into `dx`, this is the location at which our string starts
- Set a counter in `cx`
- Retrieve the byte at `[dx + cx]`. If 0, return, else `mov` to `al`
- `int 10h`
- Increment `cx` and jump back to point 3

The problem is nasm will only let me use `bx` as an index register. I believe this restriction's purpose isn't to make someone's life more difficult, so that would imply there's something wrong with my implementation. What is is, how can I overcome it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 16-bit mode you have to use BX. E.g. [see here](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Addressing/lecture.html):

> For 16-bit addressing, the offset value can be in one of the three registers: BX, SI, or DI

Comment: Well, if that is the only option, how can I change my implementation to bypass this restriction?

Comment: @szczurcio: Copy the value into BX?

Comment: Well, of course. Excuse me, my brain must've shutdown for those 10 minutes.

Comment: @szczurcio: Happens to the best, especially when writing 16-bit assembly :-S

Comment: For 16-bit addressing on a 80386+ we can also use the 32 bit register in combination with the address size instruction prefix.